# How to get the type of the returned object from .POST ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Im using ajax .POST to run php script that suppose to return true/false. Im returning true/false using "echo" in my script. But after i get the result back to JS i compare the received text in an IF statement that never works! here is my code

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'admin_checkuser.php',
     data: {action: window.myId},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {

if (output == "true"){
```

and here is the php script that being called

```
include_once('class.MySQL.php');

$userid = $_POST['action'];

$oMySQL = new MySQL();
$query = "Select * FROM videotable WHERE uid = '$userid'";
$oMySQL->ExecuteSQL($query);
$bb = $oMySQL->iRecords;
$aa = $oMySQL->aResult;


if ($bb == 0){
    $query = "INSERT INTO videotable VALUES ('','$userid','true')";
    $oMySQL->ExecuteSQL($query);
    echo 'true';
    exit();
}else{
    $sharing = mysql_result($aa,0,"share");
    echo $sharing;
    exit();
}
```

I made sure that i receive true\false by doing "alert(output)" and it always displays true\false so i really dont understand why my IF statement fails even when alert(output) shows true

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to parse the type of an ajax response tends to be super unreliable, in my experience.

For that reason, I (now) make darn sure that whenever I write a server side function that is meant for returning ajax data, I keep it perfectly in line with my own set response "standard", and then set my response type in the ajax method to JSON.

Doing so makes handling errors much more predictable.

An example of a *standardized* response would be:

```
$ajaxResponse = array(
  'data' => $someData,
  'result' => true,
  'message' => 'your yadayada was succesful',
  'timestamp' => time()
);
print json_encode($ajaxResponse);
```

and in ajax, your response would be like:

```
success: function( response ) {
   if(response.result) {
      alert(response.message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this isn't much help but you could try:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'admin_checkuser.php',
     data: {action: window.myId},
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(output) {

if (output) { ... }
```

and

```
echo json_encode(true);

// echo json_encode($sharing);
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery documentation gives more detail on what this call returns: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status;
>   and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery
>   1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

It looks like you are expecting the data that is returned from the AJAX call to be the string `"true"` in your test, so if that isn't passing it must be you are getting back something other than this exact string.

I recommend using the net tab of Firebug in Firefox to see the XHR request and to examine the response of what you are getting back to see if it is something other than what you expect.

Comment: 10x! Ill try that. And when I do "alert(output)" I do see that i get back "true", maybe "alert" throws the other irrelevent parts of the output object?